# jQuery Banner cancel function when mouseenter over a button

Tags: jquery, mouseenter

I have a banner with 3 images that I wish to fade in and fade out using jQuery. I have this part working fine with the following code:

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
        initBanner();
  startLoop = setInterval(initBanner,50000);

  function initBanner(){
   $j("##image1").delay(10000).fadeOut(1500, function(){
    $j("##image2").fadeIn(1000, function(){
     $j("##image2").delay(10000).fadeOut(1500, function(){
      $j("##image3").fadeIn(1000, function(){
       $j("##image3").delay(10000).fadeOut(1500, function(){
        $j("##image1").fadeIn(1000);
        //inMotion = false;
       });  
      }); 
     }); 
    });
   }); 
  }
```

However below the banner are 3 links which have an image related to them. When I mouseenter on the buttons I want to change the image that is fading in and out to the image related to the button.

I have tried

```
clearInterval(startLoop)
```

however this waits for the animation to finish before clearing. What I want is to be able to stop the animation immediatley and fade in the relative image.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your methods look a little bit odd, anyway to immediately stop all current animations you need to invoke the `.stop()` method to the animated element. You should pass in two arguments, both set to `true` which indicate (clearQueue && jumpToEnd);

```
function stopBanner() {
     clearInterval(startLoop);
     $('##image1, ##image2, ##image3').stop(true, true);
}
```

Again, you should reconsider your code. Caching DOM refs is a pretty important thing here for instance.

Ref.: [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)